# SQL query shorthand for not selecting null columns when doing select all

Tags: sql, sybase

when I do:

```
SELECT *
 FROM SOMETABLE
```

I get all the columns from SOMETABLE, but I DON'T want the columns which are NULL (for all records). How do I do this?

Reason: this table has 20 columns, 10 of these are set but 10 of them are null for certain queries. And it is time consuming to type the columnnames....

Thanks,

Voodoo

Comment: Got example data & expected output?

Comment: Too lazy to type out the column names?! Seriously... Think about that again.

Comment: sounds fishy enough to me to think that maybe it's a normalization issue.  the columns should be rows in another table.

Comment: @Randy: Changing columns into rows would *not* be normalization, unless the columns currently comprise repeating groups.

Comment: @Tomalak - Ok I thought about it. Again. And yes you may call it laziness, but I was just wondering if there was such an option!

Comment: The shorthand is pretty longhand, but no one has posted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL supports the `*` wildcard which means *all columns*.  There is no wildcard for all columns except the ones you don't want.

Type out the column names.  It can't be more work than asking questions on Stack Overflow.  Also, copy & paste is your friend.

Another suggestion is to define a **view** that selects the columns you want, and then subsequently you can `select *` from the view any time you want.

Comment: +1 Most SQL engines support selecting meta-data about table structure and so on. Tapping into this resource to select relevant column names and even generate complete SQL statements programatically can't be that hard either.

Comment: @Tomalak: Yes, but that tells you the list of all columns in a given table, not the ones you don't want for a specific query.

Comment: It is an excellent idea, about using views. Thanks guys! And Bill - Yeah it is more work than asking it on Stack Overflow :) c'mon....

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do, but kind of complicated.  You can retrieve the list of columns in a table from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.  For each column, you can run a query to see if any non-null row exists.  Finally, you can run a query based on the resulting column list.

Here's one way to do that, with a cursor:

```
declare @table_name varchar(256)
set @table_name = 'Airports'

declare @rc int
declare @query nvarchar(max)
declare @column_list varchar(256)
declare columns cursor local for select column_name 
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = @table_name
open columns
declare @column_name varchar(256)
fetch next from columns into @column_name
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    begin
    set @query = 'select @rc = count(*) from ' + @table_name + ' where ' + 
        @column_name + ' is not null'

    exec sp_executesql @query = @query, @params = N'@rc int output', 
         @rc = @rc output

    if @rc > 0 
        set @column_list = case when @column_list is null then '' else 
            @column_list + ', ' end + @column_name


    fetch next from columns into @column_name
    end

close columns
deallocate columns

set @query = 'select ' + @column_list + ' from ' + @table_name
exec sp_executesql @query = @query
```

This runs on SQL Server.  It might be close enough for Sybase.  Hopefully, this demonstrates that typing out a column list isn't that bad :-)

Comment: on Sybase you need to use the sysobjects/syscolumns tables, which MS still has as compatibility views.

Comment: Thanks, I will look in to it thoroughly - but it is definitely more work than typing in the names :)